# Lumen Eloquent save() don't update data at database

Tags: php, eloquent, lumen

I have buyer model, but when i want to change current it's data and save it, it won't save. $buyer->save() return 1 but data at my database won't change.

P.S.
My database has id, created_at and updated_at fields. And $buyer is not empty, it's object with data that i request ('pCode', 'banned', 'hwid')

**My code**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\TGOBuyer as Buyer;

class SubController extends Controller
{
    public function ban($key){
        $buyer = Buyer::where('pCode', $key)->select('pCode', 'banned', 'hwid')->first();
        if (!$buyer || $buyer->banned)
            return response()->json(['wrong' => 'key']);

        $buyer->comment = 'test';
        $buyer->banned = 1;
        $buyer->save();
    }
}
```

**Buyer model**
    namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TGOBuyer extends Model {
    protected $table = 'buyers';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'banned', 'comment', 'pCode', 'hwid'
    ];
}
```

**Update**
I tryed to return $buyer->id and it gives me null, i don't get it why it happens.

This is my db

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buyers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pCode` (`pCode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `hwid` (`hwid`),
  KEY `pID` (`pID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=22468 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it. I just need to include **id** to my select query. Now all work's fine.

```
$buyer = Buyer::where('pCode', $key)->select('id', 'pCode', 'banned', 'hwid')->first();
```